# Sticking Cat6 Cable With Hot Melt Glue Gun

Tags: networking, cable, cat6, cat5

I'm installing new network cables in my house and at some points I have to fix them on door or wall corners. 
Can I use hot melt stick gun? Could that momentary heat be harmful to cable?
I'm using good quality Cat6.

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt it but this sounds like a seriously suboptimal solution compared to purpose designed cable management.

Comment: When you put the glue on the corners and gaps they are left behind so it looks very clean. However I agree with TomTom, when taken-off they tear off paint behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally yes, you can do it. I would not though - sticky glue sucks to remove things. Any shop will have little clamps that you hammer into the wall on nails.